# How to set the speed of the scrolldown in git pager?

Tags: terminal

Is there a command line tweak to set the scroll-down speed?
For example, after typing:

```bash
git diff
```

I can press 'Enter' to scroll down and show more content.
I want this to scroll faster.
If not, maybe is there a global setting, not just for git?

Comment: This isn't related to git, it's related to pagers. Look at your pager `git config --global core.pager` and learn is bindings. You can probably use the default `less` bindings of ctrl-f / ctrl-b for forward and backward full pages. And ctrl-d / ctrl-u for half page jumps.

Comment: It's not about programming -- it's a basic infrastructure question.

Comment: Use the space bar to scroll by a full page. Use `b` to scroll back a full page. Use arrow keys to scroll by a single line.